# Не получается провести регистрацию пользователя.Использую NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, регистрация

Подскажите пожалуйста - что неправильно в коде?
Присылает результат: "status code 200".Мне необходим "status code 201".

NSMutableURLRequest* signUpRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staging.api.kiteflightapp.com"]
                                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                             timeoutInterval:15.0];

```
NSString *api_key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"register?api_key=&g4sksgk0kspscc4oogo8wow0w0ocossg000og0so"];
NSString *name_first = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name_first=&john"];
NSString *name_last  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name_last=&Logan"];
NSString *email_address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email_address= &test1ios@test.com"];
NSString *password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"password=&010101"];
NSString *device_token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"device_token= &123456"];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *currentSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];


[signUpRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[api_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[name_first dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[name_last dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[email_address dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[signUpRequest setHTTPBody:[device_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];



[signUpRequest setValue:@"http://staging.api.kiteflightapp.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

if (currentSession != nil) {

}

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask2 = [currentSession dataTaskWithRequest:signUpRequest
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Response: %@ %@\n", response, error);



                                                        if (error == nil) {

                                                            NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                            NSLog(@"result json: %@", jsonArray);


                                                        }
                                                    }];

[dataTask2 resume];
```

Comment: header type странный какой то, и '&' во всех полях подозрительный

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, а как лучше их написать? Я просто только начал с этим работать - не во всё въезжаю.

Comment: посмотреть в документации, что там должно быть и это написать :)

Comment: @спасибо за навигацию!)))

Comment: а что вы ожидаете? я это у себя запустить не могу, что за сервис вы используете не знаю. максимум что могу вам указать, это то, что я уже и написал - content-type, это указатель, что именно передается, например 'video' или 'json' но не то, что у вас. И у вас в параметрах везде '&', который используется для разделения query, например `login=123&password=456`, так что ваши & посреди строки, скорее всего что то портят и сервер не может разобраться, что вы ему впихиваете. ну вот в целом все, что можно сказать по вашему вопросу.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Так я и говорю - спасибо что подсказали куда "копать":)

Answer (score 0):

Что тут точно неправильно - это использование несколько раз подряд `setHTTPBody`. Похоже, что API ожитает от тебя urlencoded запрос, его надо делать примерно так:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027668/sending-post-data-nsurlsession

Про работу с компонентом нуно читать тут:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest

А вообще перед работой с сетью нужно понять концепцию HTTP-запроса и url-encioded POST в частности. Начать можно тут:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Comment: спасибо. Вопрос уже решил. Через отдельный класс, где разбил на потоки и в каждом сделал отдельный запрос.
Спасибо!